# Use \pgfplotsinvokeforeach with parameter

Tags: pgfplots, numbering, plot, loops, parameters

I'd like to use \pgfplotsinvokeforeach with a parameter to draw different plots with different colors.

What I tried is \pgfmathsetmacro but this does not work (see example, the value is fixed at 100).

Does anybody know the reason for this? And is it possible to define a parameter inside the \pgfplotsinvokeforeach-environment?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,font= \footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle,xlabel = $x$,ylabel = {$y$},samples=100,domain=-0.9:4.2,grid=both,minor tick num=1]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-2,0,2,4,6}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{(#1+2)/8*100};
\addplot[blue!\m!red] {(3-#1)/4*x^2+(#1-2)*x+1} node[pos=.55,above] {$u=#1 (\m)$};
\draw[blue!\m!red] (axis cs:{2,#1}) circle (2pt);}
\draw (axis cs:{0,1}) circle (2pt);
\draw (axis cs:{4,5}) circle (2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `\addplot` commands are accumulated in the loop, with `\m` still unexpanded. When the plots are finally drawn, the current value of `\m` is used, which is its last one, `100.0`.

You can put the loop body into a macro:

```
\newcommand\myplot[2]{%#1 = color mix, #2 = plot parameter
  \addplot[blue!#1!red] {(3-#2)/4*x^2+(#2-2)*x+1} node[pos=.55,above] {$u=#2 (#1)$};
  \draw[blue!#1!red] (axis cs:{2,#2}) circle (2pt);
}
```

and make sure that all of its arguments get expanded before calling it:

```
\expandafter\myplot\expandafter{\m}{#1}
```

The order of arguments is not arbitrary: with the `\expandafter` commands I can reach only into the first argument, so the first argument has to be `\m` and the second one is the loop value.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\myplot[2]{%
  \addplot[blue!#1!red] {(3-#2)/4*x^2+(#2-2)*x+1} node[pos=.55,above] {$u=#2 (#1)$};
  \draw[blue!#1!red] (axis cs:{2,#2}) circle (2pt);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,font= \footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle,xlabel = $x$,ylabel = {$y$},samples=100,domain=-0.9:4.2,grid=both,minor tick num=1]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-2,0,2,4,6}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{(#1+2)/8*100};
  \expandafter\myplot\expandafter{\m}{#1}
}
\draw (axis cs:{0,1}) circle (2pt);
\draw (axis cs:{4,5}) circle (2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What an amazing solution!  Btw, how did you ever instantly know  that \expandafter needs to be used twice in the same line as in \expandafter\myplot\expandafter{\m}{#1},, and that {\m}cannot switch with {#1}?  (I am wondering how many 10k hours you spent to reach such a level of expertise in tikz/pgf)

Comment: @waterstone The 'tricks' you are addressing are actually plain TeX features, and now that you've seen how `\expandafter` works, you will remember and be able to use it yourself. Whether `\m` works or has to be expanded all depends of whether the commands further down will do expansion. Instead of inspecting the code (here of the `xcolor` package) I just try the code. If `\m` works, we are done, otherwise we need `\expandafter` to replace the macro name `\m` by its value. If you are familiar with programming languages: it resembles the difference between call-by-value vs. call-by-reference.

Comment: @waterstone Regarding the 10k hours: If you take a look at [my profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/110998/gernot?tab=profile) you will understand that I really had plenty of time. Actually, during the first few thousands of years there wasn't much distraction.